# Bootstrap 4 - How to center mobile modal title?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm a beginner with bootstrap. My website is under bootstrap 4.
I have a modal that on PC, it is left aligned which is what I want. On mobile I'd like the title to go from the left alignment to the top of the div so its more readable.

Currently it looks very squished. How can I do this correctly?

I tried to do display:flex; under the modal css but nothing changed its still on the left side when viewing on mobile, even the text overlaps since the title is long.

Comment: Please provide minimal code for us to see. Read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Use a media query to adjust the styling based on the screen size.

Add a custom class to the modal title and add the appropriate styling to the media query:

```
<h5 class="modal-title modal-title-custom">Modal title</h5>
```

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .modal-title-custom {
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
  }
}
```

Adjusting the breakpoint to center the title: [Bootstrap 4 Breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/)

If `text-align` doesn't do the trick, you can try using `justify-content: center;` - [CSS justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).